Exporting large MS Access table to SharePoint fails
I am facing problem to export an MS Access table to SharePoint. It has 224223 records and the export process aborts at the middle after prosessing around 140K records showing an error "System Resource Exceeded". Screenshot attached.
Any kind help will be much appreciated!
Regards,
Hasan
Export aborts with error

My MS Access database is in the latest format (ACCDB).

SharePoint site is Modern.

I tried to export entire MS Access database and to export that particular table seperately, and failed in both attempts

I also wrote a VBA code that creates chunks of 4000 records, pushes each chunk to the table being exported. But that approach failed as well.


Please let me know if you need any further information.

A bit of a challenge to push up that many records. SharePoint tables when used with Access are about good for 5,000, maybe 10,000 rows. I pushed one table to 80,000 rows. But 1/4 of a million rows (250,000) as you have probably going to be too much. If SharePoint server is "on site" as opposed to some hosted plan, then get the admin to turn off governors and limits for such tables. So, if this is a LAN and the SharePoint server is on site, then you might be able to make this work.

Thank you very much @AlbertD.Kallal for your kind note. This is frustrating, really!

SharePoint linked tables are for small tables only.
Even if you could succeed in exporting the table, you would probably run into severe performance issues:
MS Access & Sharepoint limitations

Thanks a lot, Gustav, yes, I agree with you :(
